# Twilio LocalVideoTrack overriding start and stop events

Tags: angular, typescript, twilio, twilio-api

is there a way to override the started and stopped events to perform actions when video is started or stopped?

I tried the following but it is not working:

```
this.videoTrack = screenTrack as LocalVideoTrack;

this.videoTrack.stopped = function (event) {
    //TODO: disable buttons
};

this.videoTrack.started = function (event) {
    //TODO: enable buttons
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resolved it:

```
    this.videoTrack.once("stopped", () => {
      //TODO: disable buttons
    });

    this.videoTrack.once("started", () => {
      //TODO: enable buttons
    });
```